# Scrollto jquery error when clicking a Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, scrollto, scrollspy

I'm using bootstrap 4 and have a dropdown menu, and I have a script for scrollspy and scrollto. When I click to initiate the dropdown menu the console shows the following error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://example.com
at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
at new r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at r (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:27)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Here's the contents of the scripts.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".nav-link,.dropdown-item").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.active').not('.carousel-item.active').removeClass('active');
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 50
    }, {
        duration: 1e3,
    });

    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example',offset: $(t).offset().top });
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    return false;
});

});
```

Line 27 called out in the console is:

```
scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 50
```

The anchor it has an issue with is the href used for the top level item in the dropdown - here's the html:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Compute</a>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A demo codepen could be really helpful. Anyway, so far the error I see is in this line:

```
var t = $(this).attr("href");
```

You are storing the "href" attribute of the clicked element in variable "t". It's storing the "href" value only as a string. so the "t" is just a string, not a jquery element. That's why it doesn't have any offset() or other jquery goodies available.

I think you meant to store the element itself when clicked. For that you need to store only the element like this:

```
var t = $(this);
```

Now this "t" represents the clicked element wrapped by jquery($) functionalities. You can use "t" anywhere you need instead of $(this). For example, in line 27 :

```
scrollTop: t.offset().top - 50
```

If this still doesn't work please update your post with a codepen/jsfiddle link so that I can dig further.

Comment: Thanks for that - however - whilst the error didn't occur - smooth scroll stopped working.  I've put together a quick codepen.  If you click on the nav link "compute" you'll see the error in the console.  Here's the pen:  https://codepen.io/steveshead/pen/wONPym

Comment: It seems to scroll smoothly with my above change and enough content to scroll. Here is my [pen](https://codepen.io/khairul_anik/pen/draJVd) forked from yours.

Comment: Thanks - but - scrolling isn't the issue.  Both scroll and scrollspy work.  Like I mentioned above, without your edit, click on the link "compute" then go to the console and check the error message.  I'll update my pen to include content to scroll to.